# How to rotate coordinates taking into account that OpenCV adds black borders to the image when rotating with WarpAffine?

Tags: python, opencv, rotation, computer-vision, coordinates

I have this image:

[image: 1]

and I have the coordinates of the white circle's center. I have this other image:

[image: 2]

, they're the same image but the second one is rotated 4° using OpenCV's WarpAffine. What I want to do is calculate the white circle's center coordinates in the 4° image, taking into account that OpenCV's WarpAffine adds black borders to the image when rotating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply the coordinates of the circle on the transformation matrix from WarpAffine: (x* y* 1) = TrMat * (x y 1)T

Theory [is here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html#tutorial_homography_What_is_the_homography_matrix). In Python: [numpy.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)